# YA novel where a thief meets a disguised princess

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

So its been a few years, but its a fantasy series where there is a thief who lives in the city (His mother and sister died traumatically) and a princess. The princess decides to go into the city in disguise and they meet. To add more info, the boy had some sort of magic, and the princess was friends with her maid. There may have been something to do with wolves in the title. Read in 2020.

Comment: As a self-answer, you will not be able to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons for another 46 hours or so, but we highly encourage you to do so in two days time.

Answer (score 7):

*[The Demon King](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6342491-the-demon-king)* by Cinda Williams Chima! Finally found it after years.

[image: Front cover of The Demon King]

> Times are hard in the mountain city of Fellsmarch. Reformed thief Han Alister will do almost anything to eke out a living for his family. The only thing of value he has is something he can't sell—the thick silver cuffs he's worn since birth. They're clearly magicked—as he grows, they grow, and he's never been able to get them off.
>
> One day, Han and his clan friend, Dancer, confront three young wizards setting fire to the sacred mountain of Hanalea. Han takes an amulet from Micah Bayar, son of the High Wizard, to keep him from using it against them. Soon Han learns that the amulet has an evil history—it once belonged to the Demon King, the wizard who nearly destroyed the world a millennium ago. With a magical piece that powerful at stake, Han knows that the Bayars will stop at nothing to get it back.
>
> Meanwhile, Raisa ana'Marianna, princess heir of the Fells, has her own battles to fight. She's just returned to court after three years of freedom in the mountains—riding, hunting, and working the famous clan markets. Raisa wants to be more than an ornament in a glittering cage. She aspires to be like Hanalea—the legendary warrior queen who killed the Demon King and saved the world. But her mother has other plans for her...
>
> The Seven Realms tremble when the lives of Hans and Raisa collide, fanning the flames of the smoldering war between clans and wizards.